# Is there a way to debug an RScript call in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Imagine I run an R script from the command line, like this:

```
Rscript prog.R x y z
```

and I want to examine the code at a certain line.

Presently, I can't just debug it interactively within RStudio because I don't know how to pass in the arguments.

As it is designed to be run from the command line, how can I debug the script via the command line / outside of RStudio?

Comment: Rstudio does provide debugging tools. Can you write your whole script as a function in R and pass x y z as arguments to that function?

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn I reckon that the OP is interested in calling [tag:rstudio] debugging tools when the R script is called via `source` function. When executed via **Cmd + return** the RStudio enters debugging mode. This does not happen when the script is called via `source` function.

Comment: Does your script get the arguments by calling `commandArgs()`? So you want a way of being able to "fake" command arguments when calling a script with `source` in RStudio?

Comment: Unfortunately unlike Visual Studio and VS Code there does not seem to be a way with RStudio to provide arguments to RScript that can be subsequently debugged in RStudio. After googling around, it seems to me that RStudio way of enabling debugging of scripts with arguments is to allow passing arguments in a config file https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/config/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: Just a hunch, but have you added `browser()` to the line in the script you want to examine? Also, [here is a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668869/is-there-a-way-to-debug-an-r-script-run-from-the-command-line-with-rscript-exe) on debugging from the terminal/cmd line.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't tried that but I'll do that next time I run into an issue.

Answer (score 3):

If your only problem is passing command line arguments to a script in Rstudio, you can use the following trick.

Your script probably accesses the command line arguments with something like:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
```

After which `args` contains a character vector with all the trailing command arguments, which in your example would be  `c("x", "y", "z")`.

The trick to make your code run in Rstudio without any changes is simply to define a local function `commandArgs` that simulates the arguments you want. Here I also take care of the case where `trailingOnly = TRUE` although it's rarely used in practice.

```
commandArgs <- function(trailingOnly = FALSE) {
    if (trailingOnly) {
        c("x", "y", "z")
    } else {
        c("Rscript", "--file=prog.R", "--args", "x", "y", "z")
    }
}
```

Once `commandArgs` is defined in the global environment, you can run your script in Rstudio and it will see `"x", "y", "z"` as its arguments.

You can even go one step further and streamline the process a bit:

```
#' Source a file with simulated command line arguments
#' @param file Path to R file
#' @param args Character vector of arguments
source_with_args <- function(file, args = character(0)) {
  commandArgs <- function(trailingOnly = FALSE) {
    if (trailingOnly) {
      args
    } else if (length(args)) {
      c("Rscript", paste0("--file=", file), "--args", args)
    } else {
      c("Rscript", paste0("--file=", file))
    }
  }
  # Note `local = TRUE` to make sure the script sees
  # the local `commandArgs` function defined just above.
  source(file, local = TRUE)
}
```

Let's imagine you want to run the following script:

```
# This is the content of test.R
# It simply prints the arguments it received.

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
cat("Received ", length(args), "arguments:\n")
for (a in args) {
  cat("- ", a, "\n")
}
```

This is the result with Rscript:

```sh
$ Rscript --vanilla path/to/test.R x y z
Received  3 arguments:
-  x 
-  y 
-  z
```

And you can run the following in R or Rstudio:

```r
source_with_args("path/to/test.R")
#> Received  0 arguments:

source_with_args("path/to/test.R", "x")
#> Received  1 arguments:
#> -  x

source_with_args("path/to/test.R", c("x", "y", "z"))
#> Received  3 arguments:
#> -  x 
#> -  y 
#> -  z
```

Comment: this even works with OptionParser from optparse! Thanks @asachet!

Answer (score 0):

This solution may solve your problem:
[Is there a way to debug an R script run from the command line with Rscript.exe - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71652362/2792056)

```
ipdb.r <- function(){
  input <- ""
  while(!input %in% c("c","cont","continue"))
  {
    cat("ipdb.r>")
    # stdin connection to work outside interactive session
    input <- readLines("stdin",n=1)
    if(!input %in% c("c","cont","continue","exit"))
    {
      # parent.frame() runs command outside function environment
      print(eval(parse(text=input),parent.frame()))
    }else if(input=="exit")
    {
      stop("Exiting from ipdb.r...")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For hacking commandArgs(), it's also possible to just overwrite the `base::commandArgs()` with your own version instead of masking it, since the base environment comes unlocked.

For the part of your question on debugging, you can perform `traceback()` as usual with any `source()`d scripts. Also just want to refer to this function [`dump.frames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/debugger.html). Through this function you can dump the stracktrace to a file at error and look at it later.