# Rscript debug using command line

Tags: r, debugging, command-line-interface

I wonder if anyone knows how to debug R script in a linux environment using command line. For example, in python we can use pdb. We first set a break point (pdb.set_trace()), we then can use command like 'c','n','s','b', etc. to debug the python code in the linux environment. I have been searching lots of information for R debugging, but so far I did not find a similar function in R. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: When you say "command line" do you mean you're running the script via something like `Rscript file.R`, or do you mean you're calling `source()` from within R?

Comment: If the former (`Rscript`), I think the answer is unfortunately `cat` (or `message` or `warning` or some form of logging). If on the R console (`Rterm`, RStudio, or similar), consider http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html

Comment: @joran, I mean use Rscript file.R.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks, let me take a look.

Comment: If your normal use is `Rscript`, then your "`pdb`-equivalent" is `R`. R's debugging support is "just okay" but not on the same level as `pdb`, `gdb`, or debugging techniques available for many programming languages/environments.

Comment: Maybe http://www.math.ncu.edu.tw/~chenwc/R_note/reference/debug/Rdebug.pdf helps

Answer (score 0):

There's no native way to debug Rscript in the command line, but you can use a kind of hacky workaround I whipped up with `readLines` and `eval`.

```
ipdb.r <- function(){
  input <- ""
  while(!input %in% c("c","cont","continue"))
  {
    cat("ipdb.r>")
    # stdin connection to work outside interactive session
    input <- readLines("stdin",n=1)
    if(!input %in% c("c","cont","continue","exit"))
    {
      # parent.frame() runs command outside function environment
      print(eval(parse(text=input),parent.frame()))
    }else if(input=="exit")
    {
      stop("Exiting from ipdb.r...")
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage in an R file to be called with Rscript:

`ipdbrtest.R`

```
a <- 3
print(a)
ipdb.r()
print(a)
```

Command line:

```
$ Rscript ipdbrtest.R
[1] 3
ipdb.r>a+3
[1] 6
ipdb.r>a+4
[1] 7
ipdb.r>a <- 4
[1] 4
ipdb.r>c
[1] 4
```

I would encourage anybody using this to expand upon it for greater debugging functionality.